# Java's Arrays.copyOf method constructs a new array of type Object separately

Tags: java, arrays, copy

In the copyOf method of Arrays in the Java source code, When the new array type is Object, the new array is allocated separately using new, while others use the newInstance method of Array.

```
@HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate
public static <T,U> T[] copyOf(U[] original, int newLength, 
                               Class<? extends T[]> newType) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T[] copy = ((Object)newType == (Object)Object[].class)
        ? (T[]) new Object[newLength]
        : (T[]) Array.newInstance(newType.getComponentType(), newLength);
    System.arraycopy(original, 0, copy, 0,
                     Math.min(original.length, newLength));
    return copy;
}
```

Why does the new type Object use `new` alone while other types use the `newInstance` method?

What is the generic type `T` here? Is it the new type or what?

Comment: Re: "*Why does the new type Object use new alone while other types use the newInstance method?*" - I am not entirely sure why the two cases exist in the first place. I can tell, however, that we cannot call `new T[newLength]` due to the fact that `T` is a generic parameter. --- "*What is the generic type `T` here? Is it the new type or what?*" - Yes. It is the element-type of the array returned (as indicated by the fact that the method returns `T[]`).

Comment: I *suspect* that in some circumstances, getting the component type `Class` of `Object[].class` can give you `null`.   For example, while the JVM is bootstrapping, before the `Class` object for `java.lang.Object` has been created and fully initialized.  Or that might (just) have the case in some older Java releases.  (JVM bootstrapping is mysterious.)  Anyway, if you call `Array.newInstance(null, ...)` the javadoc says you get an NPE,